# I am building a react web app with PHP API backend. But SESSION is not maintained

Tags: php, reactjs, api, session-variables

I have written a react app with a PHP backend. I have a login area and have got this working great. This then redirects the user to another part of my app. So far so good.

But I was relying on the app maintaining session to check the user has permission to certain apis etc.

so this is how I am setting the session when user logs in

```
if( $passwordconfirm ){
   $_SESSION["sitekey"]["adminuser"]["id"] = $u->id // loaded user id
}
```

Then when checking to load another resource

```
if( isset( $_SESSION["sitekey"]["adminuser"]["id"] ) ){ // never passes this
  return array( "data" => $pages );
}
```

It seems every fetch request I make creates a new session, I can confirm this as output session ids and every single one was different. Any reason for this or way I can get around this?

Comment: Are you doing `session_start()` at the top of every page?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I am, well sort of, it is in a file called include.php which is a sort of custom autoloader and is called on every request.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually being called on the page in question? `return array( "data" => $pages );` looks like this is ran inside a function? Is this function called before or after your include.php page is included?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yeah positive, sorry I didn't put the whole file up, as I thought it all wasn't needed. But it is called in a method, and the  class is definitely instantiated after session_start() is called, I have been error_logging it all for a couple hours now